# Global variable problem, event is missing and not fired

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I have a contract like below:

```
contract SimpleBidding {

    address contractOwnersAccount;

    // request information
    address public client;
    uint barcode;

    // bidding information
    uint expectedProposals;
    address bestVendor;
    uint bestPrice;

    // events
    event AssetRequested(address client, uint barcode);

    /* Constructor */
    function SimpleBidding(address _account) {
        contractOwnersAccount = _account;
    }

    /* checks if the time limit has been reached and ends the contract */
    function dispose() {
        suicide(contractOwnersAccount);
    }

    /* Used by clients to request assets and start bidding.     */ 
    function requestAsset(uint _barcode) {
        // save the requester
        client = msg.sender;

        // save the asset barcode
        barcode = _barcode;

        // create the event
        AssetRequested(client, barcode);

        // initialize the bidding process
        expectedProposals = 2;
        bestPrice = 999999;
    }
}
```

I realized that somehow the global variable `address public client;` does not work (it does not create the event). When I change it to `var client = msg.sender;`, it works and creates the event. I know it, because I have a watcher printing a log when the event is fired.

By the way, I call the function as below:

```
simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset(5555, {from: eth.accounts[2]})
```

Any ideas? There is no error message or something like that I found.

Comment: This seems to work for me on Browser Solidity, even if I change the account from which it's sent. (By changing "Transaction origin".) The event is successfully triggered.

Comment: It works for me also on Browser Solidity. I realized that if I add more statement to the function, it does not work properly. It is probably about this `gas` stuff, but I am a newbie and dont know much how to do.

Comment: If you think it's a gas issue, just do `simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset(5555, {from: eth.accounts[2], gas:1000000})`

Comment: Also, if you post a tx hash from the mainnet or public testnet, we can tell you for sure if it's a gas issue.

Comment: `simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset(5555, {from: eth.accounts[2], gas:1000000})` worked for me. So it was about `gas`. But I remember for some cases, the geth console is giving warning when there is not enough balance for example when you try to execute a function. For this problem, I had no warning at all. I am just curious, when we call the function as `simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset(5555, {from: eth.accounts[2]})` (without the gas paramater), what is the default gas amount used? Do you know?

Comment: @ÖnderGürcan  Please post the answer that you found.  For default gas see ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/default-value-for-gas-in-sendtransaction  (Would also be good if an answer for Parity can be added by someone.)

Comment: The reason it gives a warning if there's not enough balance and not if there's not enough gas is simply that it is quite difficult to guess how much gas your transaction will need. With balance, it's an easy calculation to see if the cost of the transaction is greater than your balance.

Comment: Thank you. The worst thing is that, I searched for an answer during several days and noone was able to tell me that it could be about `gas`.